Why don't we consider the initial phase in the superposition to form a stationary wave?
In the derivation of the equation for a stationary wave, we consider two oppositely travelling but otherwise identical waves $\xi_-(x,t) = a \sin(kx - \omega t)$ and $\xi_+(x,t) = a \sin(kx + \omega t)$ which we superpose to get $\xi(x,t) = 2a \sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)$. Why don't we consider the initial phases of the two travelling waves e.g. $\xi_-(x,t) = a \sin(kx - \omega t + \alpha)$ and $\xi_+(x,t) = a \sin(kx - \omega t + \beta)$ to get $\xi = 2a \sin\left(kx + \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\omega t + \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2}\right)$? Thanks.

We can choose where to take the origin for our distance measurements, and we can also choose when to start our stop watch, and we can always make our choices so they eliminate the initial phases.
Suppose we have, as you say:
$$\begin{align}
\xi_-(x,t) &= a \sin(kx - \omega t + \alpha) \\
\xi_+(x,t) &= a \sin(kx + \omega t + \beta)
\end{align}$$
and let's choose new distance and time variables:
$$\begin{align}
x' &= x + A \\
t' &= t + B
\end{align}$$
If we substitute these into our equations we get:
$$\begin{align}
\xi_-(x',t') &= a \sin(k(x' - A) - \omega (t' - B) + \alpha) \\
\xi_+(x',t') &= a \sin(k(x' - A) + \omega (t' - B) + \beta)
\end{align}$$
which after a quick rearrangement gives us:
$$\begin{align}
\xi_-(x',t') &= a \sin(kx' - \omega t' - kA + \omega B + \alpha) \\
\xi_+(x',t') &= a \sin(kx' + \omega t' - kA - \omega B + \beta)
\end{align}$$
and now all we have to do is choose our constants $A$ and $B$ such that:
$$\begin{align}
- kA + \omega B + \alpha = 0 \\
- kA - \omega B + \beta = 0
\end{align}$$
which we can do because we have two simultaneous equations in two unknowns, and the equations become:
$$\begin{align}
\xi_-(x',t') &= a \sin(kx' - \omega t') \\
\xi_+(x',t') &= a \sin(kx' + \omega t')
\end{align}$$
and we have transformed the equations to eliminate the initial phases.
You are correct that if we are not allowed to choose what to take for the origins of $x$ and $t$ then we would have to include the phases and carry them through all the calculations. But since we generally are free to choose whatever origins we want then we can eliminate the phases and not need to bother with them.
